# warning : implicit declaration of function ' crypt_r'

Tags: c, linux

I am trying to write a multi-threaded program in which I need to call the function crypt. But the compiler throws this warning. Also it doesn't recognize crypt_data as well. Any ideas?

Comment: Did you try #including the appropriate header file?  Did you inspect that header file on your system?  Did you try grepping for crypt_r in your /usr/include?

Comment: No I'm expecting to have all the functions by default...really now? Yes I have included crypt.h, and also defined _GNU_SOURCE

Comment: Hey, I'm just asking the usual questions--you wouldn't believe the simple problems people have that get solved with stuff like that.  I meant no insult of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pre-process the source of your program, e.g. by running `gcc -E` in place of `gcc -c`.  Look at the output to see if some/all/none of the crypt functions you expect are appearing in the declarations.

Answer (score 3):

You need to include appropriate header file. In this case `crypt.h`

```
 #include <crypt.h>
```

Comment: On OS X I'm getting the error `crypt.h: No such file or directory`. Where can I get it from?

Comment: You need to install libcrypt dev files.

Answer (score 1):

Declare the prototype for the function crypt (Forward declaration) Or include the header which has that.